# Frontend JavaScript request gets 302-redirected but ultimately fails

Tags: safari, xmlhttprequest, cors, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I'm trying to create an audio visualization for a podcast network, using the Web Audio API with createMediaElementSource() very similarly to the model [explained in this tutorial](https://medium.com/@gg_gina/how-to-music-visualizer-web-audio-api-aa007f4ea525). So far I've gotten it to work fine in Chrome, and [you can see it here](https://nchilla.github.io/wnsr-new-school-radio/demo/visualize.html) (note: click on the red box to start it).

**Update**: Based on discussion in the comments, it’s now become clear that the problem happens because the request gets redirected to another URL, by way of a 302 redirect.

---

However, Safari refuses to work, outputting no sound and producing no visualization although it shows the track playing. I believe it has to do with the CORS policy of the server I'm requesting the audio from, because I've alternatively tried using [this audio source](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/858/outfoxing.mp3) and it works great in all browsers. My suspicion is it's an issue arising due to [this standard](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#MediaElementAudioSourceOptions-security) of the web audio API.

The fact that it only happens in safari makes me pray that there's some easy syntactic solution either on my end or the server host's end in their CORS policy to get this to work. I'm hoping someone can point out exactly **what's going wrong in the header requests/responses that's causing this problem**. Let me know if there's any more information I need to provide. I've left a simplified version of my AudioContext code below in case a problem surfaces there.

```
//definitions
var url='https://rss.art19.com/episodes/72a3bc7e-118a-4171-8be4-125913860ef7.mp3';
//in safari it works with the link below, but not with any art19 link such as the one above.
//https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/858/outfoxing.mp3
var audiotag=document.querySelector('audio');
var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context;
var statcontext;
var analyser;
var source;
var loopf;

//on load:
context=new AudioContext();
audiotag.crossOrigin="anonymous";
audiotag.preload="none";
audiotag.src=url;
source=context.createMediaElementSource(audiotag);
analyser=context.createAnalyser();
source.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(context.destination);
analyser.smoothingTimeConstant=0.85
analyser.fftSize = 16384;

//later, on user input(clicking on red bar):
var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
function updateDisplay() {
  loopf=requestAnimationFrame(updateDisplay);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
  draw(dataArray.slice(100,150),-100,100);
}
context.resume();
audiotag.play();
updateDisplay();
```

Comment: What are the exact error messages that the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: no error messages showing in the console! just silent audio while the track plays and no output to audiocontext visualization

Comment: well an update: I was sniffing around your profile and came across your post about using a cors proxy, so i tried it out with the public demo by setting my URL source to this: https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://rss.art19.com/episodes/72a3bc7e-118a-4171-8be4-125913860ef7.mp3 and it worked! what does that indicate the problem is— is CORS still ruled out?

Comment: any ideas on non-proxy solutions? I linked the w3 standard section for the web audio API that i think dictates the behavior I'm seeing, which is supposed to arise if the source element "has been created using an HTMLMediaElement for which the execution of the fetch algorithm [FETCH] labeled the resource as CORS-cross-origin."

Comment: So I can communicate with the server host I'm making the requests to, since my client pays them for a CMS and RSS with hosted audio links; is there something I can ask them to change about their headers or CORS policy?

Comment: The request URL from the redirect works as well!!! This is the rub though- the final website is going to automatically pull the URLs from the RSS feed, and they are of the first URL's style. Is there a way to get the redirect URL within javascript and do another request with it? Duly noted on your last reply-I'll see what they say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: The maintainers of the service sending the `302` response to your request should update their backend config such that it adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to `302` responses (and any other `3xx` redirect responses) — not just to `200` OK responses.

If you can’t get them to do that, then basically you only have exactly two other options:

1. Change your frontend code to make the request through a CORS proxy; or else
2. Don’t make the request from your frontend code at all, but instead do it completely from your backend server-side code (where the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) doesn’t apply).

**Explanation**

Here’s what happens:

1. Your frontend code makes a request to a `https://rss.art19.com/episodes/….mp3` URL.
2. The `https://rss.art19.com` server replies to with a `302` redirect response that has a `Location: https://content.production.cdn.art19.com/…episodes/….mp3` header.
3. The browser receives that `302` response and checks the response headers to see if there’s an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. If there isn’t, the browser blocks your code from accessing the response from the `https://content.production.cdn.art19.com/….mp3` redirect URL. Instead the browser will stop and throw an exception.

You can sometimes fix this problem by taking the redirect URL and using it as the request URL in your frontend code. For example, rather than using `https://rss.art19.com/episodes/….mp3` in your code, use `https://content.production.cdn.art19.com/…episodes/….mp3` — since the `200 OK` response from that includes the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header).

But in many or most cases in practice, that strategy won’t work — because it’s not feasible to preemptively identify what the redirect URL will be.

Note: by design, browsers by design don’t expose redirects to frontend code. So it’s impossible from frontend code to programatically get a redirect URL and do another request with it.

Comment: If you send an Origin header, as browsers do, you do get Access-Control-Allow-Origin as you'd expect.